# continue to <label> in C# like in java

Tags: c#, label, goto

I need C# equivalent to Java’s continue ?

i have

```
for (String b : bar) {
    <label>
    try {
    }
    catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex) {
    continue <label>
    }
  }
```

how can i simulate this in C#. i need that when i get exception that i repeat code not go on.

Comment: Do you want to retry the same value? Otherwise just use continue.

Comment: yes i need to retry value again

Comment: If you catch the exception in C# and do nothing in the catch block, the loop will continue to the next item - with your code as is, it'd keep retrying the same item (and presumably continually throwing the same exception).  Are you sure that's right?

Comment: Burn the witch!! Burn them! No Gotos in this land! Not again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `goto <label>;`

Comment: so goto are not so evil. Thx foy our help, i will use goto <label>

Comment: @senzacionale, `goto` is not evil, just very dangerous. The fact that `goto` exists in C# does not make it safe - and your chosen use seems unsafe in a number of ways.

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to continue to the next loop iteration, use `continue`.

c# also has labels (which you can jump to with `goto`), but please don't use them.

Comment: You forgot to add that goto's are evil :p

Comment: Only non-local goto's are evil. C# disallows non-local goto.

Comment: From a discussion on loops and continues (in Eric's replies to comments): "Note that the C# goto was carefully designed to be less hazardous than other languages' gotos." http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/01/11/continuing-to-an-outer-loop.aspx

Comment: `continue` is just a special kind of `goto`, so if `goto`s are really evil, then `continue` is a special kind of evil (which happens to be generally safer due to the restrictions). Everything has its place and proper use, including (rarely) `goto`s.

Comment: This is the only time goto should be used.

Comment: @JonathanAllen If I was going to call a case the "only" case for `goto` it would be for explicit fall-through - banning fall-through in C# no doubt stopped a lot of bugs, but there's a reason C had it, and in C# we can do `goto case 2;` at the end of another case-block to then do the code in that block. Still, I wouldn't restrict `goto` this much entirely. I came here from googling for an alternative where I'm using `goto` in C# to re-enter a nested loop from the beginning, to see if there's an alternative - there isn't.

Comment: I am very much against using goto inside a switch block, especially in C# where the switch block is so incredibly limited. As for fall-through, that was never a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply add a control variable?

```
foreach (String b in bar) {
  bool retry;
  do {
    retry = false;
    try {
      // ...
    }
    catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex) {
      retry = true;
    }
  } while (retry);
}
```

or

```
var strings = bar.GetEnumerator<string>();
var retry = false;
while (retry || strings.Next()) {
  var b = strings.Current;
  retry = false;
  try {
    // ...
  }
  catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex) {
    retry = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you're trying to do is wise at all - do you have any reason to expect that you won't hit a scenario where you always get an exception on a particular iteration?

Anyhow, to do what you want to do without `goto`, look at this:

```
foreach (String b in bar) { 
    while(!DidSomethingWithThisString(b))
        ;
  } 

bool DidSomethingWithThisString(string b)
{
    try { 
    } 
    catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex) { 
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```